# Is there an efficient way to bullet-proof a program without try...except?

Tags: delphi, exception

I've got a Delphi 6 client-server application where the server is essentially:

```
initialize;
repeat
  try
    getInput;
    putOutput;
  except
    on e: exception do writeln(e.message);
  end
until false;
```

During development, bugs (such as a pointer exception) were rare but the server would be able to keep running.  Now that it's in production the server *seems* debugged and it's tempting to remove the `try...except` because it adds substantial execution overhead to the server, but then if an exception were to occur it would stop the server.

One solution would be to have a parent process simply restart the entire server, and bypassing initialization on restart would effectively reproduce what `try...except` accomplished, but there wouldn't be any record of what caused the exception, and restarting with or without initialization actually creates a lot of unwanted "state" issues, especially with client connections.

Is there some way to override or amend exception handling so that when the exception happens it's recorded somewhere (such as in the system event log or %errorlevel%) before the programs quits and is restarted or (better:) recovers, but without the overhead of an all-encompassing `try...except`?

The ideal solution would record the exception but resume execution at the level of the `repeat...until`.  Perhaps by doing something like saving the address of the `repeat` in some accessible global, then make any exception unwind the call stack and resume at that saved address?  (Which I guess is what `try..except` essentially does, but is there a way to avoid the overhead it imposes when there aren't exceptions?)

Comment: How does having the try...except block add substantial execution overhead to your server?

Comment: Analyse what can raise exceptions

Comment: @Robert: the 'repeat' loop executes faster without try..except.  I forget how much, but it was substantial.

Comment: @David: the input/output routines are thousands of lines of code.  Bad pointers would be the most likely cause of any future exception and have been the only issue before.  We're probably damned with slower execution if we leave try/except in, and damned with an unexpected exception if we take try/except out.

Comment: Move `try..except` out of the loop

Comment: @user: then the server doesn't keep running after the exception.  I guess we could do repeat try repeat until except until.

Comment: @user24 that could be semantically identical with an extra outer loop

Comment: make a nested loop, say 1000 iterations, without `try .. except`

Comment: Programming errors on your part should kill the server. Attempting to recover is dangerous. Why not fix all of your mistakes? What other exceptions are raised?

Comment: All known mistakes were fixed, it's just no one wants to gamble another won't turn up, and in the mean time it's more important to keep the server running even after an exception, which it managed to do during past exception tests.

Comment: Imagine you have a buffer overrun bug. Now you might be corrupting memory. Continuing after an error could result in using the corrupted memory. Sounds dangerous to me. I'd prefer to kill the server in that case and have it restarted.

Comment: @WitnessProtectionID44583292, you say that the input/output routines contains thousands of of lines of code, yet the try/except frame slows down the loop with 25%. This means that most of the time (>> 99%), the I/O routines does nothing. Seems like a polling scenario to me, and should be refactored to be event driven instead.

Comment: I agree with David. An exception might leave the program in an instable state. Things might go on, but either produce wrong results, or cause other damage. I'd rather stop the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on Serg's suggestion:

```
repeat
  try
    repeat
      getInput;
      putOutput;
    until false;
  except
    on e: exception do writeln(e.message);
  end
until false;
```

Has the same behaviour but moves the `try .. except` outside the innermost loop.

However, I'd be amazed if this had any discernible impact on performance.

Comment: Yes, this is the double-repeat realized after user246408's comment.  try/except inside the inner repeat slows things down a lot.  With try/except outside the inner repeat it's as fast as no try/except at all as long as no exception happens, and the outer repeat keeps the server running if there ever is an exception.

Comment: Yes. But I'd still be amazed if you could measure a perf difference.

Comment: try/except inside repeat/until slows the loop about 25%.

Comment: That doesn't seem consistent with your earlier comments. I still believe that there's more to this than has been presented here.

Comment: I agree, the fact that the try/except frame has that impact on performance would imply that the I/O routines are polling data (most of the time there is nothing to do).

Comment: @LURD Even that wouldn't really explain it. It might take slightly longer round to typical empty polling loop iteration, but so what? If there's nothing to do, does it matter if you take a few clocks more to do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on David and Sergs suggestions...

If the complexity of your loop is as low as your posted code suggests (or could be reduced to such a level of simplicity) then it may be practical to provide **both** behaviours, subject to a command line switch to either enable or disable runtime errors via exception handling.

Parse the command line at startup to determine the mode of operation and set an indicator variable accordingly.  e.g using an enum:

```
type
  TServerMode = (smHighThroughput, smDiagnostic);

var
  ServerMode: TServerMode;


if FindCmdLineSwitch('d') then
   ServerMode := smDiagnostic
else
   ServerMode := smHighThroughput;
```

You could of course use a setting in a configuration file or database table if a command line parameter is not desirable or practical for whatever reason.

However you go about it, you provide the ability to run the server in "high throughput" mode or "recoverable diagnostic" mode with a minimum of duplicated syntax:

```
try
  case ServerMode of
    smDiagnostic     : repeat
                         try
                           getInput;
                           putOutput;
                         except
                           on e: Exception do .... // etc      
                         end;
                       until FALSE;

    smHighThroughput : repeat
                         getInput;
                         putOutput;
                       until FALSE;
  end;

except
  on e: Exception do .... // etc      
end;
```

Note that even in **HighThroughput** mode the above example captures information about any exception that causes server termination.  The **Diagnostic** mode logs all exceptions but attempts to keep the server running.

You can then default to **HighThroughput** mode with the option of enabling **Diagnostic** mode in the event that you need to diagnose a server that seems unusually unstable.

Having said all that, I would try to definitively quantify the impact of the `try..except` on the loop before going to great lengths to engineer around that impact.

Comment: try/except inside repeat/until slows the loop about 25%.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you are measuring this.  I created a comparison case and found that yes there was a difference but only of 13%.  That was with all of the syntactical elements but no real "meat" in the processing.  In terms of actual elapsed time overhead with this stripped back to measure just the impact of adding try/except inside the loop, that 13% difference was actually only 0.0003 of a second.  But that overhead will be an absolute elapsed time, so as a percentage of the overall loop iteration, as you add real work to the the loop the overhead will likely become all but negligible.

Comment: I agree with David and others that there is more to this than is clear from the question if it really does add "25%" in your case.  I'm also rather dubious about the use of a %age measure of the overhead.  As they say in retail, you can't bank a percentage and to paraphrase here... a watch doesn't have a Percent Hand).  I wonder if in cases where your exception handling is necessary it is the problem causing the exceptions and the handling of them that is accounting for the overhead rather than the try/except itself in the absence of exceptions.  i.e. correlation, not causation.

Answer (score 0):

- Drop an ApplicationEvents on a central place in your application.
- Implement the OnException Event.
- Delete the local try...except to remove overhead.

In the exception event you can do anything including log the exception.
If you want to add something special to the exception it is possible to still have a local try..except and modify the E.Message and then call raise. Then the global exception handler will be called with the modified message.

Comment: I doubt this is a VCL forms app. What you see in the `repeat` loop is the main processing loop. `OnException` is based on the main VCL message loop. So, not applicable here.